# UITabBar in splitview detailview

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I've got an ipad app with a splitviewcontroller.
in the right viewcontroller I've got a MapView, a Tableview and I'd like to insert a Tabbarview displaying multiple views (each having its specific controller).

Up to now, I do not find a way to insert that UITabbarcontroller.

How should I branch everything ? is it pure coding or may I do it through IB ?
is there any web site or book explaining the thing ?
cheers,

Tib.

Answer (score 2):

You want to add tabbarcontroller to your split view at detail view side and its very simple. create as many viewcontrollers subclasses with xib for ipad as u want to put in tabbarcontroller.Open Mainwindow.xib then do this,

- expand your splitview , u have two things navigationcontroller(which in turns contain rootview controller),detailview controller(right side view).
- Open your library just drag tabbar controller to exectly onto detailviewcontroller ,so it will replace  that detailviewcontroller.
- now expand this tabbar controller u can see viewcontroller 1 - viewcontroller 2 etc.
- Now simply select view controller 1 , open attributes  [press command 1 attribute] and select nib file of your detailview controller  and on command 4 attribute select controller as detailview controller.
- Reapet this for view controller 2 in tabbarcontroller but in this select nib file and controller file as u want or as new file created by u  and save close IB. run program select landscape then u can see its done.
- even u can add more than two tabbar items bye just drag  viewcontroller from library exectly on tabbarcontroller then expand tabbarcontroller then u can see new viewcontroller then repeat above process.

Comment: just a heads up for folks out there: this probably won't work for iOS 5 and later since it's now all in storyboard.